# Will angels still enter my house if pictures of family and inanimate objects such as trees, pots, surahs, etc are hung up?

Tags: halal-haram, malaikah, image

Recently I have learned about the rulings of pictures, but I am still a bit confused as to what pictures are allowed in the house. I fear that angels will not enter the house I currently live in, and I do not want that to be the case.

Comment: @Sayyid : the question you posted is Very specific and he is asking a general ruling about pictures, so its not a duplicate